# Running the Cytoscape Arena3DwebApp.jar application in Android or with Termux (or if absolutely necessary, in a VM)

Tags: android, linux, cytoscape, termux

I am interested in running the Cytoscape Arena3DwebApp.jar in Android or with Termux (or if absolutely necessary, in a VM), to explore knowledge graph functionality and extensibility, is it possible?

This is just information prospecting at this stage. I have not yet ventured any solutions.

Comment: Looks like no efforts are being made!

Answer (score 0):

At this point, Cytoscape has not been tested on Android, although it should certainly run in a VM.